Nav2 robot does not move (Path Planning, Ackermann Steering)
I am migrating from the turtlebot3 to my own vehicle with nav2. The robot does not move after a Nav2 goal is given, and i suspect the trajectory is not feasible.
I have the x-Axis pointing in driving direction and setting a 2D Pose Estimate does align the robot in driving direction, when i apply a Nav2 Goal i get a trajectory but the arrows within are orthogonal to the driving direction, i guess this makes it unfeasible for the robot to follow it.
Where can i change these settings? Or am i wrong about the transformations? Is x in driving direction a convention for nav2?
Edit: The orientation comes from the map frame, however, i still see no movement of the robot, it might be more related to the settings i guess
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930152.477387555] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930152.492994788] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930146.433 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930153.077604571] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930147.061 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930153.679257406] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930147.634 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930154.289066914] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930148.234 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930154.889846097] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930148.834 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930155.471113928] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930149.433 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930156.065253570] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930150.034 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930156.330377415] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930156.642716022] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1724930150.634 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930156.990832274] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930157.098119951] [behavior_server]: Exceeded time allowance before reaching the Spin goal - Exiting Spin
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930157.098221214] [behavior_server]: spin failed
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1724930157.098241042] [behavior_server]: [spin] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1724930157.117086711] [behavior_server]: Running wait
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1724930157.263304383] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at 



Can you edit the question with the error logs, more detail about your situation, possibly a video, and config files? I can't really understand your problem, what's going wrong, or how you have it setup.

I found my error, i had to remap cmd_vel as ackermann_steering_controller does listen to topic "ackermann_controller/reference_unstamped", for anyone else encountering the problem with Nav2, you can copy my solution here
    GroupAction(
        actions=[
            SetRemap(src='/cmd_vel', dst='/ackermann_controller/reference_unstamped'),
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                    PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('nav2_bringup'), 'launch', 'bringup_launch.py'])
                ),
                launch_arguments={
                    'params_file': PathJoinSubstitution(
                        [FindPackageShare('iav_rover_nav2_bringup'), 'params', 'nav2_params.yaml']
                    ),
                    'map': PathJoinSubstitution(
                        [FindPackageShare('iav_rover_nav2_bringup'), 'maps', 'empty_map.yaml']
                    ),
                }.items(),
            ),
        ]
    ),

